# How can I write different texts after each interval?

Tags: android, libgdx

I want to write different texts after some intervals. To do that i wrote this codes which is not working

```
@Override
public void render() {      
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    float delay = 5; // seconds

    Timer.schedule(new Task(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            batch.begin();
            font.draw(batch, texts[flag],200, 200);
            batch.end();
        }
    }, delay,5);
}
```

It would be great if you help me figuring out what I am doing wrong with explanation.

Comment: Well how exactly is it not working? Please explain exactly what the problem is.

Comment: I need full working code of render() method to solve this problem. I am pretty noob.

Comment: Well nobody is going to write your code for you. Explain what the problem is and we can help you but it's your app and you are gonna have to do the work.

Comment: noone will do it as already said. And you cant shedule a timer every render cycle! you need to do this outside of the render AND you cant draw outside of the render thread so you cant draw in a timer task.

Comment: Actually i see a white screen, without any text.

Comment: Then how can i draw after each 5 sec? Please give me some links where i can understand these concept elaborately.

Comment: Your text has same color as background.

Comment: No text color is red.

Comment: Is it possible to delay the render() method as my intended interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using those things correctly. The `render()` is called every gameloop (about 60 times per second, depending on the FPS). So you schedule a new `TimerTask` 60 times per second...
Also you `draw()` inside your `TimerTask`, so only if the `Timer` event is fired.
You see a white screen, because you are telling the `Screen` to overdraw himself with a white color every render loop:
`Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
 Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`

Note, that the `Color(1, 1, 1, 1)` is white with full opacity.

What you should do instead is:

in your `show()`, if this is your screen class or in `create`, if this is your `ApplicationListener`/`Game` class you add this:

```
float delay = 5; // seconds
text = "This is the 1. text";    // text is a member variable (String)
nb = 1;                             // nb is a member variable (int)
Timer.schedule(new Task(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        nb++;
        text = "This is the " + nb + ". text";
    }
}, delay, 5);
```

This changes the text every 5 seconds, from "This is the 1. text" to "This is the 2. text" to ...

In your render you then need to draw() it:

```
public void render() {      
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    font.draw(batch, text, 200, 200);
    batch.end();
}
```

This should work. I suggest to read some tutorials about libgdx and how to use its gameloop.